# Convertendo camel case para underscore em Ruby

Tags: ruby, formatação

Existe uma função pronta que converte Strings em camel case para strings separadas por underscores?

Gostaria que algo assim:

```
"CamelCaseString".to_underscore
```

retornasse `"camel_case_string"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rails' ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore) 
adiciona underscore a classe String usando esse código:

```
class String
  def underscore
    self.gsub(/::/, '/').
    gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
    gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
    tr("-", "_").
    downcase
  end
end
```

Pronto:

```
"CamelCase".underscore
=> "camel_case"
```